# Run selenium java project without giving the source code

Tags: selenium

I'm building a test automation script using java, selenium, TestNg and cucumber. Is there anyway to run and get the result without sharing the source code ?

Comment: Yes, you can configure the jenkins or any other CI server to execute the test scripts. They can get the result from there.

Comment: oh thanks... ill try and let you know :)

Comment: bundle as a fat jar and then obfuscate it.